# How to get roman enumerate symbols and remove the margin?

Tags: enumerate

I want to use the `enumitem` package in order to customize the margins of an enumerate list. I also want to use the `enumerate` package in order to customize some enumerate list and use (i), (ii), etc.. symbols in some list.

Building the following code with `pdflatex test.tex`:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \lipsum[2]
\item \lipsum[2]
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*]
\item \lipsum[2]
\item \lipsum[2]
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[(i)]
\item \lipsum[2]
\item \lipsum[2]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

produces:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\enit@endenumerate ->\enit@after 
\endlist \ifx \enit@series \relax \else \if...
l.12 \end{enumerate}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is a clash between the `enumitem` and `enumerate` packages. A possible solution is to use only `enumitem`, and use the `[label=(\roman*)]` option of `enumitem` to get (i), (ii).
The code:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*]
\item \lipsum[2]
\item \lipsum[2]
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
\item \lipsum[2]
\item \lipsum[2]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

works fine.

Comment: B.t.w., what do you mean with ‘remove the margin’?

Comment: Inside enumerate, the left margin increases. Because the list is already within an environment (within an exercise in my particular case), this causes an excess, unnecessary, margin. Using [leftmargin=*] move the whole block to the left.

Comment: You also  can use the option  `wide=0pt`.